# Formatações RTF.

Tags: c#, html, rtf

Tenho um RTF no banco de dados que salva as cores, o enter, entre outras ações que o usuário deu. Estou usando o seguinte código para converter o RTF para mostrar no HTML, porém estou perdendo todas essas formatações, tem algum jeito de corrigir isso?

```
    public static string rtfToTxt(this string txtRtf) {
        using(var generalRTF = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()) {
            if(txtRtf.Length > 5 && txtRtf.Substring(0, 5).Equals("{\\rtf")) {
                try {
                    generalRTF.Rtf = txtRtf;
                    return generalRTF.Text;
                } catch(ArgumentException) {
                    return txtRtf;
                }
            } else {
                return txtRtf;
            }
        }
    }
```

Um exemplo seria este RTF:

```
 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1046{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}  {\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 ENTER  \par   \par \cf1\b\f1\fs22 Letra Colorida\cf0\b0\f0\fs17   \par }
```

Onde eu teria um enter e uma letra colorida e eu acabo por perder essas formatações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa converter o valor RTF para o HTML e não pegar o valor Text do RTF.

por Exemplo, onte tem paragrafo no RTF `\par` no HTML você tem que colocar um `<p></p>`.

Veja esses artigos:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e